# Can't Ping - Wireless network of home

Tags: networking, windows-xp, windows-vista, ping, wifi

This may seem like other ping problem, but I have tried a lot before posting it here.

I have a linksys WRT54G -  firmware v8.00.8. I have two laptops one windows vista (192.168.1.99) and Windows Xp (192.168.1.13) connected on WiFi . The Router's IP address is 192.168.1.4, and default gateway is the ADSL modem (192.168.1.1) connected through wire.

The problem is that laptops can not ping each other, they can ping the gateway and the linksys router, and both can access internet.
Following has been tried (I am pinging from XP machine to Vista):

1. I saw that **arp entires** for Vista machines were not being populated, so I added static ARP  entries.

   *192.168.1.99          00-19-7e-70-d0-4e     static*
2. I checked on **ethereal** that an ICMP packet for MAC address of Vista machine does go out from XP machine towards the Vista machine, but never reaches the Vista machine. So its get eaten by the Router?
3. I added Vista machine to **DMZ** in my linksys router, so that all the ports are open (In case it was an issue).
4. **Firewalls** , **antivirus** etc were turned off, echo was enabled explicitly on vista, file sharing, network discovery were turned on. Network type was set to private.
5. Unchecked everything in **Router;s firewall**, even though they are only meant for WAN requests.

Is there anything else that I should try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some wireless points will stop clients from seeing each other, you need to disable client/ap isolation:

http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/client-isolation-ap-isolation-how-does-work-774.html

Comment: Thank you so much... AP isolation was the problem.. phew... should have come here earlier :)

Comment: No worries :)))

Answer (score -2):

You can´t have a network equipment with two interfaces in the same network.
It seems you have the lan(wifi) and wan(router) in the same subnet.
In this way the linksys is not able to handle the traffic properly.

Comment: I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a comment.

Comment: it´s basic networking!